# Constant distance between agents throughout the simulation

Tags: java, anylogic

I am making a pedestrian model wherein the the pedestrian must be set to have a distance between other agents.

I have tried using references from similar questions using limiting  number of agents in a queue etc.
But is there a syntax to maintain distance among agents?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's from an animation point of view only, in the ped source you can define the diameter of the pedestrian to for example 2 meters, which will make the pedestrians repel each other if they come into close proximity below the defined diameter (as if they were crushing with each other)...

I don't know if this work in all cases, because if you create them together, they might continue being together... I also don't know if it works for very large distances.

Also I think they value more their destination than the fact they are too close to other agents.

The other option is to program it yourself, which will be the most accurate way to do it.